# How call http request only once after some time

Tags: angular, api, http, input, rxjs

I have one component in Angular 11 that has many inputs which were included dynamically in a table,
after the user insert the currency value into one of that input I call an API to calculate everything.

But because of that, I call many times the API, so I want to call only once after some seconds, whatever Input I use, then I tried to use *debounceTime* but I still call for each input. I tried to figure it out or search on the internet to make one queue or something like this for call only, however I couldn’t reach a solution

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK7JD.png)

```
this.campoCalculoPercentual.changes.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {
  this.campoCalculoPercentual.forEach((element) => {
    const keyups = fromEvent(element.nativeElement, 'keyup');
    const result = keyups.pipe(debounceTime(1000));
    result.subscribe((x) => this.calcular.emit());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `debounce` or `throttle` techniques to handle this.
Here is a detailed guide on how it works: [css-tricks - debouncing throttling explained](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/)

Popular libraries like underscore/lodash has such helper methods built in, for eg:

- [`_.debounce`](https://underscorejs.org/#debounce)
- [`_.throttle`](https://underscorejs.org/#throttle)

Answer (score 0):

```
let throttle = function (fn, throttleTime) {
    let timer
    return (...arg) => {
        const temp = Date.now()
        if (!timer || timer - temp >= throttleTime) {
            fn(...arg)
            timer = temp
        }
    }
}

// implement OnInit's `ngOnInit` method
<button (click)="throttleLogIt('i am arg')">Save</button>

throttleLogIt = () => { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.throttleLogIt = throttle(this.logIt,2000)
    /**
     * this is step will return a throttle function,
     * this function will  includes a closure ,
     * every fire click will check the value timer of closure 
     */
}

logIt(msg: string) {
    this.logger.log(`${msg}`);// i am arg
}
```